# WooCommerce Multisite Categories Issues

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wpmu

I have a multisite installation of WordPress and WooCommerce.

The problem I have is, the categories seems to be shared all across the different sites.

I create a product category on the first site and it gets automatically added to the others. Same thing happens if I delete a category. It will be deleted on all the sites.

I just updated WooCommerce and WordPress yesterday thinking it might just be out of date and developed a " random feature "

Is anybody had this problem before? I need categories to be individual on every site. Fun thing is, this only happens to product categories. It doesn't apply to products. If I create a product on a site, it stays there and doesn't get shared all across the network.

Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got it fixed. I had a script that synced all the terms between the sites. Needless to say, `product_cat` is a term.